# How to setup Visual Studio project FTP to a remote IIS Server?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I have an ASP.Net project that I've been working on my local machine and I've successfully uploaded my application files from my local machine to the remote IIS server. My issue occurs when I make changes to my code through the IIS remote server, sometimes the changes that I have made do not appear or work. The way I fixed the problem was upload the updated project into the IIS server.
I've read a bunch of articles online and some people are mentioning the IIS cache or temp file that must be cleared.
Is there a way for me to establish an FTP connection from my local machine to the remote IIS server so that when I push changes it would automatically update the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish your website by using visual studio publish tool. Which will automatically deploy code to your FTP location on publish. You just need to configure your FTP remote server. Right click your website project and click **publish**

[image]

Then select **IIS,FTP** from side nav and click publish

[image]

Then select FTP from **Publish method** drop down and start configuring your application and after that click on **Validate Connection** to test if it had connected to FTP properly and click next and complete configuration and your code will be deployed to that FTP remote server

[image]